# Cannot check for updates in Excel for Mac 2016

Tags: macos, mac, ms-office, software-update

I'm trying to updates Excel for Mac 2016 and Word for Mac 2016. Apparently when I go to help I should be able to see a 'Check for updates' menu option. However, I cannot see this menu option - see screenshot. how do I update Excel for Mac 2016 and Word for Mac 2016?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what is going on with your install of Office 2016 Mac but mine has that option under help.

If I launch Microsoft Autoupdate that way it shows me that the actual app is here:

```
/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MAU2.0
```

You should be able to launch the Microsoft AutoUpdate.app manually from there.